# If we have $T^2 = S^2$ then $T=S$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

$T$ and $S$ are two linear self-adjoint and positive and bounded operators defined on complex Hilbert space $H$. show that if we have $T^2 = S^2$ then $T=S$.

I know that $T^2$ and $S^2$ should have the same characteristic function and eigenvectors. So should we conclude that the same thing for eigenvectors of $T$ and $S$? And then what can we do?

Comment: Have a look at Rudin, Theorem 12.33.

Comment: Spectral theorem would be the first place to look.

Answer (score 1):

Every positive element in a $C^*$-algebra has a unique positive square root. Your assumption means that the positive operator $T^2$ has positive square roots $S$ and $T$. Hence, $S = T$.

Comment: Is there elementry for that? In the level of kreyszig book.

Comment: @a.p I'm not familiar with that book, but it is in Murphy's book "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory"  which is very accessible. Basically, this follows from functional calculus.